# C++ Template class: error: no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, templates, pass-by-reference, function-declaration, pass-by-rvalue-reference

I have the following template class:

```
template <typename T> class ResourcePool {
    inline void return_resource(T& instance) {
        /* do something */
    };
};
```

Then, in my **main** function, I do:

```
ResoucePool<int> pool;
pool.return_resource(5);
```

And I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to `ResourcePool<int>::return_resource(int)`
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this call

```
pool.return_resource(5);
```

a temporary object of type `int` with the value 5 is created as the function's argument.

A temporary object can not be bind with a non-constant reference.

Declare the function like

```
template <typename T> class ResourcePool {
    inline void return_resource( const T& instance) {
        /* do something */
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a temporary to a function that expect a reference. This bind can not be done. Try:

```
template <typename T> class ResourcePool {
    inline void return_resource(const T& instance) { // <---
    /* do something */
    };
};
```

or

```
template <typename T> class ResourcePool {
    inline void return_resource(T instance) {  // <----
    /* do something */
    };
};
```